# In tensorflow, how to enumerate training data (compared to pytorch)

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

In pytorch, this is how I enumerate training data.

```
for epoch in range(0, args.epoches):
    for i, batch in enumerate(train_data):
        model.update(batch)
```

`train_data` contains multiple `batch`es and batches are getting enumerated and updating the model, which is very clear to me.

---

I think this is a basic example of how tensorflow treats the batches.

```
for step in range(num_steps):
    batch_data, batch_labels = generate_batch(batch_size, num_skips, skip_window)
    feed_dict = {train_dataset : batch_data, train_labels : batch_labels}
    _, l = session.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Maybe this is a very obvious question, but I'm not clear how enumerating training batches is handled by `session.run` in tensorflow. I can't find batches are getting looped through in the code. All I see is `feed_dict` and I assume it handles the looping.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow has a `History` object for this purpose. You get `History` object as a return from the `model.fit()` method.

A `History` object and its `History.history` attribute is a record of training loss values and metrics values at successive epochs, as well as validation loss values       and validation metrics values (if applicable).

Hope this is what you need.